# What is the relation between the normal derivative and derivative at a point of any function?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Is the normal derivative the average of the derivative at all points of the function? If not what is the mathematical relation between them.

Comment: Do you mean to ask the difference between, say, $f'(x)$ and $f'(a)$?

Comment: Or are you referring to ${\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}}$ vs ${\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}}$?

Comment: Normal derivative is a directional derivative taken in the direction normal to some surface or curve, so is particular case of directional derivative, if you this have in view. Differentiability at some point implies existing directional derivatives taken in any direction.

Answer (score 1):

The derivative of a differentiable function $f(x)$ is another function $f'(x)$. It’s not related to the ‘average’ of anything. It takes as an input (*the point at which we wish to know the derivative*) and spits out the value of the derivative at that point.

E.g. If $f(x)=\sin x$, then $f'(x)=\cos x$. This is the derivative function. The derivative at a specific point, say $x=0$, is $$f'(0)=\cos 0 =1.$$